# How should I get all the tweets of an specific hashtag?

Tags: twitter

I'm trying to develop some code in order to get all the tweets that were generated with certain hashtags, then parse them and finally analyse them. I believe I've already thought and solve the last two parts of this but I'm having some trouble with the first one. I've already read the Twitter Search API documentation but I haven't realised yet how to do this. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to retrieve the tweets sent recently, you should use the [`search/tweets`](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets) endpoint of twitter' REST API, and mention the hashtag inside `q` parameter

In case you want to listen to tweets containing the hashtag and receive them in real time, then twitter's [streaming API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/filter) is what you should use (`statuses/filter` endPoint).

Have a look at the documentation on twitter's website, there's also plenty of information on how to do this all around the web.

Comment: Thank you, it helped a lot! Now, do you think it would be possible to call any of the functions without registering an app? I've understood that it's compulsory to make some kind of authorization in order to make the HTTP GET and get the data (in fact, I've tried to build a request URL and received a bad request response).

Thanks!

Comment: It is not possible to get the data without registering an app unless you get the data from a data partner such as [Gnip](http://gnip.com), (note: I work for Gnip).